# I want to add PermLvl to my index.js -- DISCORD.JS

Tags: node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

So, recently i started making my own bot, Im not the most experienced person too, but I know a bit of what im doing. I went off the basic Discord.js index provided on Discord.js Guide, and just added my own code to it, without actually touching the command handler.

For some commands I wanted to have a perm level that only with that perm level

> permlvl 1 = Manage Message
> ^ not actual code just an example, That way only users with that perm level can use it.

Here is my index.js At the moment.:

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./commands/config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const { dir } = require('console');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();




const Fun = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/Fun/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of Fun) {
    const command = require(`./commands/Fun/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


const General = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/General/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of General) {
    const command = require(`./commands/General/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


const Information = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/Information/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of Information) {
    const command = require(`./commands/Information/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.elevation = message => {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
    let permlvl = 0;
    if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) permlvl = 1;
    if (message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) permlvl = 2;
    if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_GUILD")) permlvl = 3;
    if (message.member.id === message.guild.ownerID) permlvl = 4;
    if (message.author.id === config.devID) permlvl = 5;
    return permlvl;
  };


client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} has started, with ${client.users.cache.size} users, in ${client.channels.cache.size} channels of ${client.guilds.cache.size} guilds.`); 
    client.user.setActivity(`Serving ${client.users.cache.size} users in ${client.guilds.cache.size} server.`, { url: 'https://www.twitch.tv/discordsstream', type: 'STREAMING' });
)};

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();


        const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;


    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }


    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${config.prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }

try {
    command.execute(message, args);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
}
});
```

with the exception of my other client.on and some of the main code in client.on and stuff at the bottom. This is everything having to do with the command handler in the index, Here is the config in the actual commands:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'ping',
description: 'See the bots response time!',
usage: '',
guildOnly: false,
permLevel: 0,
aliases: ['responsetime', 'pong'],
execute(message, args, async) {
}
```

The thing is, It works with 0 errors when the command is run, But the permlvl doesnt work,

I tried adding it the the "say" command as only permlvl 1 which is

```
        if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) permlvl = 1;
```

but members could still use it. -- They dont have the permissions on their roles either.

I tried a few things with the config, I tried replacing it with AwesomeCommandHandler, in which that code it didnt work, So i reverted back. I searched a few discord.js sites, And some Stack Questions, but no where could I find the answer, itd be great if someone could help me, Either in finding the answer or giving it, Either way.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check if the user permLevel is higher or equal to the command one:

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./commands/config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const { dir } = require('console');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();




const Fun = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/Fun/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of Fun) {
    const command = require(`./commands/Fun/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


const General = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/General/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of General) {
    const command = require(`./commands/General/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


const Information = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/Information/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of Information) {
    const command = require(`./commands/Information/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.elevation = message => {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
    let permlvl = 0;
    if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) permlvl = 1;
    if (message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) permlvl = 2;
    if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_GUILD")) permlvl = 3;
    if (message.member.id === message.guild.ownerID) permlvl = 4;
    if (message.author.id === config.devID) permlvl = 5;
    return permlvl;
  };


client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} has started, with ${client.users.cache.size} users, in ${client.channels.cache.size} channels of ${client.guilds.cache.size} guilds.`); 
    client.user.setActivity(`Serving ${client.users.cache.size} users in ${client.guilds.cache.size} server.`, { url: 'https://www.twitch.tv/discordsstream', type: 'STREAMING' });
)};

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();


        const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;


    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }


    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${config.prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }
    
    const userPermLevel = client.elevation(message);
    const commandPermLevel = command.permLevel;
    if(commandPermLevel > userPermLevel){
        return message.channel.send('You do not have required permissions');
    }

try {
    command.execute(message, args);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
}
});
```